# JavaScript: build tree like structure from list of json objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of the JSON objects

```
var files = [{name:"1.xml", path:"folder1/1.xml", tag:"folder1", type:"file"},
{name:"2.jpg",      path:"folder1/folder2/2.jpg", type:"file", tag:"folder1/folder2"},
{name:"3.doc", path:"folder1/folder2/3.doc", type:"file", tag:"folder1/folder2"}];
```

I need to create the following structure

```
[
{
name:"folder1",
path:"folder1",
type:"folder",
items:[
    {name:"folder2", 
     path:"folder1/folder2", 
     type:"folder", 
     items:[
         {name:"2.xml",path:"folder1/folder2/2.xml", type="file"},
         {name:"3.xml",path:"folder1/folder2/3.xml", type="file"} 
      ]},
     {name:"1.xml", path:"folder1/1.xml", type="file"}
]}]
```

Basically, the tag property of each file has to become a folder and group the files and other tag into items collection.

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: I think Arkej means did you already try to solve it? if so, you should post that. [Also, maybe take a peek at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example

Comment: I did - https://jsfiddle.net/4j92gvnc/ - however I have trouble with recursion once the files are added to items collection.

Comment: These are JavaScript objects. JSON is a text format. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this recursive function:

```js
function buildTree(files) {
    var result = { path: '', items: [] },
        i = 0;
    
    if (!files.length) return [];
    // Sort items so they get processed in folder order
    files.sort( (a, b) => a.path.localeCompare(b.path) );
    
    (function recurse(curr) {
        var tag = files[i].tag;
        tag.substr(curr.path.length+!!curr.path).split('/').forEach( folder => {
            var obj = {
                name: folder,
                path: (curr.path ? curr.path + '/' : '') + folder,
                type: 'folder',
                items: []
            };
            curr.items.push(obj);
            curr = obj;
        });
        while (i < files.length) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (file.tag.indexOf(tag + '/') === 0) {
                recurse(curr);
            } else if (file.tag === tag) {            
                curr.items.push({
                    name: file.name,
                    path: file.path,
                    type: 'file'
                });
                i++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    })(result);
    return result.items;
}

// Sample data
var files = [
{name:"1.xml", path:"folder1/1.xml",         type:"file", tag:"folder1"},
{name:"2.jpg", path:"folder1/folder2/2.jpg", type:"file", tag:"folder1/folder2"},
{name:"3.doc", path:"folder1/folder2/3.doc", type:"file", tag:"folder1/folder2"},
{name:"4.doc", path:"folder1/folder23/3.doc", type:"file", tag:"folder1/folder23"},
{name:"5.doc", path:"folder12/3.doc", type:"file", tag:"folder12"},
];

// transform to tree structure
var tree = buildTree(files);
// Output result
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```